# Set source of image of dynamically created element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the id of the dynamically created element in `JavaScript` to set **src** as:

```
$scope.source = canvas.toDataURL();
let htmlString = "<img id='imageId' style='height: 100px; width: 100px;'>";
let doc = document.createElement('div');
doc.innerHTML = htmlString;
let image = doc.getElementById('imageId');
image.src = $scope.source;
```

But I always get image as **undefined**, because there is not method getElementById in **doc**.

How do I set the image source in this?

Comment: `querySelector` can find the image.

Comment: Why not use `image = document.createElement('img')` and then go from there?

Comment: @AleksG or better still `image = new Image()`

Comment: @Alnitak indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML elements don't have a `getElementById()` method, that method is part of the `document` instance of the `HTMLDocument` class but your var `doc` refers to the newly created `<div>`, not the document.  You could have used:

```
let image = document.getElementById('imageId');
```

However, this won't actually work until you've really put the image into the document, and that won't work until you've attached the `<div>`.

Alternatively on modern browsers (which I presume you're using as you're using ES6 syntax) you could use:

```
let image = doc.querySelector('#imageId');
```

without relying on the element being in the DOM, since the query call is rooted at the (detached) div.  That still leaves you with the (out of scope) problem of where and how to attach that div to the document.

Comment: I just did that but image is null now

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi then you have something else wrong.

Comment: Ah, right - you can't actually find the element until it has been inserted into the DOM.

Comment: So how do I do that?

Comment: depends where you want to put it, but if this is part of an Angular directive it's out of scope for this question

Comment: Thanks for your help, it does not show the error now. But actually I needed to send email html template to server (Spring) for sending emails using angularjs as frontend. It just shows the text instead of image when I alert the compiled html.